# Can wasm use sysinfo dependency?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, wasm-bindgen

I was hoping to be able to write a very small Rust package and compile it to `wasm`, that would be able to read the system RAM/CPU resources.

Is this due to browser protection for the PC?

I can use the dependencies `sysinfo` dependency and run it no problem in Rust but once compiled into `wasm`, the values are no longer available. They just return back as `0`.

```
use sysinfo::SystemExt;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console)]
    fn log(s: String);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn specs() {
    let mut system = sysinfo::System::new();

    // First we update all information of our system struct.
    system.refresh_all();

    // And finally the RAM:
    let total_ram = system.get_total_memory();
    let used_ram = system.get_used_memory();
    let available_ram = total_ram - used_ram;

    log(format!("Total memory: {} kB", total_ram)); <--- Work in Rust but return 0 in wasm
    log(format!("Used memory: {} kB", used_ram)); <--- Work in Rust but return 0 in wasm
    log(format!("Available memory: {} kB", available_ram)); <--- Work in Rust but return 0 in wasm
}
```

Comment: WASM's access to the system is restricted to whatever the runtime provides it. Generally, this means that it can't access anything that Javascript running in the browser can't access. You can look at crates like `web_sys` and `js_sys` for what is available to WASM. To answer your question directly: No, browsers do not provide system information, and even if they did, the `sysinfo` crate isn't compatible with the browser environment.

Answer (score 2):

Web assembly is unsupported by sysinfo. This triggers a dummy implementation returning `0`s.

As can be seen here: https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/sysinfo/blob/6315474256150e5f6e23bc80c0fd922b40998a58/src/unknown/system.rs#L96

Regarding the near future I would not get my hopes up to see support for web assembly. At least to me it would be also unclear to me what the meaning of the values should be. Would these values refer to the entire system, or just the memory available to Web Assembly?